# Is there a way I can delay a form field error check with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

My login screen has HTML like this:

```
        <span class="label">
            User Name
            <i class="fa"
               ng-class="{'fa-exclamation-triangle': as.vloginUserName(as.forms.login.loginUserName) != 'OK'}"
               title="{{ as.vloginUserName(as.forms.login.loginUserName) }}"></i>
        </span>
        <input class="w15r"
               id="loginUserName"
               name="loginUserName"
               ng-change="as.clearRegisterData()"
               ng-model="as.loginUserName"
               ng-minlength="3"
               type="text"
               value="" />
```

and I am using this function to check the minimum length:

```
vloginUserName = function (field) {
    if (angular.isDefined(field)) {
        if (field.$error.minlength) return "Minimum Length 5";
    }
    return "OK";
}
```

Is there a way that I could delay the presentation of the error message that says "Minimum Length 5" ?

Comment: is that for presentation purposes only? if so, you could achieve a delay through CSS3 transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **ngModelOptions** you can specify a custom list of events that will trigger a model update and/or a **debouncing** delay so that the actual update only takes place when a timer expires; this timer will be reset after another change takes place.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example35-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="debounceExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form>
    Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 5000 }" /><br />
  </form>
  <pre>username = "{{user.name}}"</pre>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('debounceExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

may be this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JjxlfW0fEoBWZzSM5GCp?p=preview) will help uh.. try this... here, the model field will be updated after   5 sec delay and the error check will occur afterwards...